# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - SimpleXLSX

Tags: php, archivo, foreach, simplexlsx

Quiero leer un archivo con extensión `.xlxs`. Uso php con la clase `SimpleXLSX`, pero cuando trato de obtener valores de estos campos, cada uno dice que "Argumento no válido proporcionado para foreach ()" Por supuesto, el archivo que uso no está vacío.

```
<form name="login" action="myself.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="file" >
    <input  class="form-control" type="submit" value="Upload" >
</form>
```

```php
   if (isset($_FILES[ 'file' ])) {

       $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX ($_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ]);

       foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $fields)
       {
            // Do something here
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando [esta librería](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx/) SimpleXLSX, te falta parsear el archivo para que el objeto que instancias tenga todas las filas.

Los ejemplos que indican dicen que lo haces así:

```
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
    print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
    // Aquí iría tu foreach en vez del print_r, por ejemplo...
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```